# Very dynamic HTML with Uno-Choice plugin within Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm a newbie to the Uno-Choice plugin.

Basically I have an XML document describing a system environment and I want to dynamically build a grouped list of servers where the user can check the artifacts he wants to release.

Here's the XML:

```
<deployments>
  <group name="Foo">
    <server name="JBoss Foo">
      <id stage="development">foo-development.com</id>
      <id stage="integration">foo-integration.com</id>
      <id stage="staging">foo-staging.com</id>
      <id stage="production">foo-production.com</id>
      <artifact>
        <id>jboss-configuration-foo</id>
      </artifact>
      <artifact>
        <id>services-ear</id>
      </artifact>
    </server>
  </group>
  <group name="Bar">
    <server name="JBoss Bar">
      <id stage="development">bar-development.com</id>
      <id stage="integration">bar-integration.com</id>
      <id stage="staging">bar-staging.com</id>
      <id stage="production">bar-production.com</id>
      <artifact>
        <id>jboss-configuration-bar</id>
      </artifact>
    </server>
  </group>
</deployments>
```

I would like to have something like the following. Note that the name of the server should change dynamically depending on what is selected in 'Stage'. This should be no problem with the Cascade Dynamic Choice Parameter.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

According to the plugin developers, that's not possible. But they think it's a good idea, so I created a [JIRA issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28617)